# Last line on a grid does not appear

Tags: c#, grid, gdi+, gdi

I am drawing a grid in a PictureBox with GDI+ and C# with the following function and values :

```
nbTilesX = 5;
        nbTilesY = 5;
        tileWidth = 64;
        tileHeight = 64;

public void DisplayGrid()
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

        for (int i = 0; i <= nbTilesX; i++)
        {
            this.graphic.DrawLine(pen, i*tileWidth, 0, i*tileWidth, nbTilesY*tileHeight);

        }       
        for (int j = 0; j <= nbTilesY; j++)
        {
            this.graphic.DrawLine(pen, 0, j*tileHeight, nbTilesX*tileWidth, j * tileHeight);
        }
        this.graphic.Dispose();     
    }
```

Here is the result : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=285423grille.jpg
(I can't directly upload the picture here because i am a newly registred user... sorry)

Both horizontal and vertical last lines are missing. Even if i put "for(int i =; i<=30;i++)", the result is still the same. Nothing is drawn outside the area.

Can someone help me ? 
Thanks,
a beginner.

Comment: Do the last horizontal and vertical lines get drawn outside the border of the area?

Comment: what happens if you hard-code the drawing of last vertical and horizontal lines. Do they appear?

Comment: Try increasing the size of your picture box. You might be drawing it, but it's outside of the [DisplayRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: if i do : this.graphic.DrawLine(pen, 0, 7 * tileHeight, nbTilesX * tileWidth, 7 * tileHeight);, nothing happens

Comment: but this.graphic.DrawLine(pen, 0, 6 * tileHeight - 100, nbTilesX * tileWidth, 6 * tileHeight - 100); draws a line

Comment: and the size of my control is 800 x 700 .. !

Comment: Are you creating a custom control? Are you overriding the OnPaint method? Or, are you creating a user control with a picture box?

Comment: We need some more information to be able to figure out your problem.  I threw a picturebox on a new form and added that drawing code, and it worked fine for me, so I suspect there's more factors in your case.  Is there another control on the form overlaying the edge?  Have you checked at runtime to make sure the picturebox is really big enough?  Try changing the background color of the picturebox to double check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the code where you instantiate your control?

When `i==5` or `j==5`, the coordinate is 320. Problem is, if your graphic is set to 320x320, that's 0-based (0 to 319), so the coordinates are outside the bounds.

Comment: that solved my problem, the zone defined by pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(...) was too small... ! Thanks a lot to you and all those who replied !